# How to set Out Parameter value from a query in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Stored Procedure, and I want out parameter `@OUT_TOTALROWS`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_SOMEPROC](@IN_USERID INT,  
                                        @IN_SEARCHFILTER VARCHAR(50),
                                        @IN_DELIVERYSTATUS TINYINT,
                                        @IN_PAGESKIP INT = NULL,
                                        @IN_PAGENEXT INT = NULL)
                                        @OUT_TOTALROWS INT OUTPUT) --TOTAL ROWS OUT HERE

-- ******** HOW TO SET @OUT_TOTALROWS FROM HERE?
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRows, --IS THERE A BEGIN WAY? DONT WANT THIS
       P.NAME
    FROM SOMETABLE PM
    join SOMETABLE_2 P ON P.ID = PM.ID
    WHERE PM.UserID = @IN_USERID AND 
    PM.DeliveryStatus = @IN_DELIVERYSTATUS AND
    (CONCAT(P.FirstName, ' ', P.LastName) LIKE '%' + @IN_SEARCHFILTER + '%' OR
    PM.Message LIKE '%' + @IN_SEARCHFILTER + '%')
    ORDER BY PM.ScheduledDate DESC OFFSET @IN_PAGESKIP ROWS FETCH NEXT @IN_PAGENEXT ROWS ONLY;
```

So, I want to know total rows before offset is applied and want to return that as Output Parameter, along with the data retrieved.

Is there any better way to get set `@OUT_TOTALROWS`?

Comment: You cannot combine variable set and rowset retrieval in a single `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I am just not a fan of using stored procedures to return query results.  You should be using a *function* not a *procedure* for this.

Answer (score 0):

let `select` of columns contain all you need into a `temp` table, then you can set `@OUT_TOTALROWS` variable in one`select`, other query will be your result set.

```
SELECT PM.ScheduledDate,P.NAME 
INTO #TEMP
FROM SOMETABLE PM
join SOMETABLE_2 P ON P.ID = PM.ID
WHERE PM.UserID = @IN_USERID AND 
PM.DeliveryStatus = @IN_DELIVERYSTATUS AND
(CONCAT(P.FirstName, ' ', P.LastName) LIKE '%' + @IN_SEARCHFILTER + '%' OR
PM.Message LIKE '%' + @IN_SEARCHFILTER + '%')


SELECT @OUT_TOTALROWS = COUNT(*) 
FROM #TEMP

SELECT 
   COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRows, --IS THERE A BEGIN WAY? DONT WANT THIS
   t.NAME
FROM #TEMP t
ORDER BY t.ScheduledDate DESC 
OFFSET @IN_PAGESKIP ROWS FETCH NEXT @IN_PAGENEXT ROWS ONLY;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TEMP', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #TEMP;
```

Comment: You cannot write two separate `SELECT` queries the reference the same `CTE` without repeating the whole CTE definition. CTEs are attached to a single final query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank for your remind my answer modify to use temp table